# Skip the first call to a mocked object in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

This is my code for the function and it's unit tests that test the same function in two separate try except blocks with different inputs:

Script:

```
from file import myfunction

in main:
try:
    myfunction(str_input_1)
except Exceptoin as e:
    print("error str_input_1")

try:
    myfunction(str_input_2)
except Exceptoin as e:
    print("error str_input_2")
```

Unit tests in a separate file:

```py
    @patch(myfunction)
    def call_myfunction_with_str_input_1(self, mock_myfunction):
        mock_myfunction.side_effect = Exception("error str_input_1")

        myfunction(str_input_1)

        mock_myfunction.assert_called_with(str_input_1)

    @patch(myfunction)
    def call_myfunction_with_str_input_2(self, mock_myfunction):

        myfunction(str_input_2)

        mock_myfunction.assert_called_with(str_input_2)
```

First test case passes just fine, but second unit test also tries to run it with the value for the first unit test:

```
raise AssertionError(_error_message()) from cause
AssertionError: Expected call: myfunction(str_input_2)
Actual call: myfunction(str_input_1)
```

Comment: Are you defining `mock_myfunction` at a top level scope? If so, it's the same object in both functions so the calls are cumulative. Make a new mock object for each test. Use a fixture to make it DRY.

Comment: @jordanm: please check the updated script, I import the function from another file into the main file.

Comment: What does your script have to do with your tests, since you are calling `myfunction` directly in the test?

Comment: @chepner: The script shows the order and the structure in which the function is called as the second unit test needs to pass the first try except block.

Comment: Please read [mcve]. What you have right now is not complete (nor even runnable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing

```py
@patch(myfunction)
def call_myfunction_with_str_input_2(self, mock_myfunction):

   myfunction(str_input_2)

   mock_myfunction.assert_called_with(str_input_2)
```

To:

```py
@patch(myfunction)
def call_myfunction_with_str_input_2(self, mock_myfunction):
    mock_myfunction.side_effect = [
        None, # call for str_input_1
        Exception(exception_error), # call for str_input_2
    ]

   myfunction(str_input_2)

   mock_myfunction.assert_called_with(str_input_2)
```

Solved the issue.